# kebab-case to PascalCase with regex

Tags: regex

I'm working on a custom snipped in VSCode. Now I want to turn my kebab-case filename to PascalCase. How do I achieve that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[^0-9^a-z]//gi}
```

This takes my filename, e.g. `quantity-change.js` and turns it to `quantitychange`.

But what I want is `QuantityChange`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
"Filename to PascalCase": {
        "prefix": "tm_",
        "body": [
            "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(?:^|-)([a-z])|/${1:/upcase}/g}"
        ],
        "description": "Convert filename from kebab-case to PascalCase."
    }
```

The `(?:^|-)([a-z])` pattern matches either the string start position (`^`) or (`|`) a hyphen, and then matches and captures into Group 1 a lowercase ASCII letter (`([a-z])`). Then, `${1:/upcase}` in the replacement part gets the value captured in Group 1 and turns it to upper case.

You may see [more about VSCode snippet creation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) ([example section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_transform-examples) is quite helpful).